# Get image color code's in RGB mode using php

Tags: php

Is it possible to get the RGB colorcode from an image using php? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [`imagecolorat`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorat.php) function.

Example:

```
<?php
$im = imagecreatefrompng("php.png");
$rgb = imagecolorat($im, 10, 15);
$r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
$g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
$b = $rgb & 0xFF;

var_dump($r, $g, $b);
```

Comment: Do i have to specify x and y co-ordinates?